# select column name from H2 with columns that have spaces

Tags: java, sql, h2

I am attempting to query from a tab delimited file with H2 and java. When I `select *` there are no problems, however, one of the columns has a space in the column name. When I try to query on just that column I get an exception:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "EXAMPLE" not found; SQL statement:
```

It appears as though it is not grabbing both words in the column name (Example ColumnName), but only grabbing the first.

This is what I have:

```
System.out.println( simpleJdbcTemplate.queryForList( "SELECT Example ColumnName FROM CSVREAD('" + fileName
                + "', null,'UTF-8', chr(9)) where send = 1;", new Object[] {} ) );
```

I'm guessing there is a special syntax to do this, but I can't seem to find it. I've tried enclosing the column name in: square brackets, single quotes, double quotes, tick marks all to no avail.

Is there a way to query H2 using columns that have spaces in the name?

Comment: just guessing, but have you tried double quotes or brackets?

Comment: Yes, I've tried enclosing the column name in: square brackets, single quotes, double quotes, tick marks all to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#quoted_name), double quotes should do the trick.
Remember to escape them correctly in Java, i.e. to just store your column name in a `String`, use

```
String exampleColumnName = "\"Example ColumnName\"";
```

Also, note it is case sensitive, from the documentation:

> Quoted names are case sensitive

Comment: Ug, I missed the case sensitive part! Thanks for finding the doc for it, that helps alot.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use brackets [] if you set "MODE=MSSQLServer" in your connection properties. Example:

```
SELECT * FROM [My Table]
```

The connection string would look something like this:

```
jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=MSSQLServer
```